# Eclipse vs IntelliJ Hot Deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea

My app configuration: Tomcat 8, Spring, Spring MVC, Hibernate.

In Eclipse I created Tomcat Server with my app added to resources.
JSP, JS, CSS and JAVA classes hot deploy works just like that.

In IntelliJ I configured Tomcat 8 Server. In Deployment tab I added `myapp:war exploded`.
I enabled `On 'update' action` to `Update classes and resources`, also i enabled `On frame deactivation: Update classes and resources`.
JSP, JS, CSS hot swap works just like that. Java classes not.

I have also checked `Settings > Build, exection, deployment > Compiler > Make project automatically`

PS. I know I can use JRebel, but in Eclipse hot deploy works without JRebel. Why it does not work in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the name for the feature is not "hot deploy" but HotSwap. It is a feature of JVM and not of an IDE. IDEs just automate the process and trigger the HotSwap of the changed class automatically when there's a new version of the class available. HotSwap is limited only to the changes that can be made to a body of an existing method.

In IntelliJ, go to Settings->Debugger->HotSwap and check the settings:

[image: HotSwap settings]

Enable **Reload classes in background** checkbox and then you can choose the behaviour, should the IDE ask you about hotswapping the classes, hotswap silently, or never hotswap the classes.

You do have to compile manually. But, if the application is deployed from an "artifact", then "Make project automatically" works for the running application even though it says the opposite (Settings -> Compiler). The inconvenience though is that automatic compilation triggers with a delay, so it is not as instant as one would expect. Compiling manually is just as simple as pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Eclipse, just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to make the project (which is actually incremental) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> if you want to compile a single file.

I'd still recommend [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) for improving the experience since it goes far [beyond what HotSwap can do](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/comparison-matrix/) and it integrates with a [large number of Java frameworks](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/misc/frameworks.html) to eliminate redeploys. And yes, I'm biased - I work for ZeroTurnaround and I'm involved with JRebel development.

UPDATE:

The initial question was rather more about the automatic redeployment of the web app in Tomcat/IntelliJ
In Run configuration, you can configure, what should be done for the 'Update' action:

[image: Update action]

The 'Update' action is invoked manually. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and search for 'Update':

[image]

So, redeployment is a rather "one-click" manual process in IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks to @koppor for the notice. The new URL is http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/misc/integrations.html

Answer (score 2):

In IJ you can set the eclipse compiler instead of the default javac compiler but still you will need to make manually.

Comment: If the application is deployed from an "artifact", then "Make automatically" works for the running application even though it says the opposite in the settings. The inconvenience though is that it has a delay, so it is not as instant as one would expect. Compiling manually is just as simple as pressing Ctrl+S in Eclipse - just the different shortcut which could be remapped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the comment in IJ next to 'Make project automatically'?

> only works while not running/debugging

To redeploy just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (make) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (make current file).

Comment: this has nothing to do with hot deployment.

Comment: IMHO it does, IJ cannot deploy anything if it did not make it first. As the OP mentioned he is expecting the make to happen automatically which is not the case while running.

Comment: You both are wrong :) The code replacement that is actually a JVM feature is called HotSwap. Hot deployment is the same as redeploying the application, which is basically same as application restart - looses the session state and re-initialises the application from scratch. So, HotSwap it is.

Comment: You both are wrong :). This question is solely about hot DEPLOYMENT. Not even the accepted answer covers that - in fact hot deployment is about MUCH More than just "restarting", at first you need to recompile, then your local webserver needs to be instructed to notice the changed bytecode - after that its a RELOAD which may or may not succeed. Please dont post wrong answers if you dont even know what the question is about, you may mislead unaware newcomers - just like you did right now.

Comment: It is more confusing discussion here! But, I wanted to have an option like publish in Eclipse. Publish means you don't need to restart the application to load your recent changes onto server.  Ctrl+F9 doing the same in IJ. This answer helped me find what I wanted. Thank you @StijnGeukens