# grails app cannot refresh automatically

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy

I write a grails app in intellij.When I create a new domain class(`Spring Loaded: Cannot reload new version of tmp.TestFkTable`),or add a new url in urlmapping.groovy(`404 not found`),or add a new method in controller(

> ERROR org.springsource.loaded.agent.Watcher - FileWatcher caught serious error, see cause
>   org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Error instantiated artefact class [class tmp.CenyController] of type [class org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass]: InvocationTargetException

),the console show erros.

I have to re-run it,then it would work as I expected...

I find a page "https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/fe7ea7ffec2fc06e8017cb633e39e67341788475" about it,after build it,I do not know how to do.Any other methods?

Comment: Grails-version is 3.1.1,groovy-version  2.4.5,JDK 1.8 64bit.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26843248/2166188

Comment: Still not work for me even I use the JRebel

Comment: which version of intellij?

Comment: @MichalSzulc The latest community edition.

Comment: Did you try to change JDK to 1.7 or Oracle JDK to OpenJDK?

Comment: @MichalSzulc I have tried jdk 1.7 but not work .

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853540/what-does-the-dynamic-classpath-flag-do-intellij-project-settings